# libgdx shaperenderer How to rotate rectangle around its center?

Tags: java, libgdx

How to rotate rectangle around its center?  I found rotate function in ShapeRenderer:

```
void rotate(float axisX, float axisY, float axisZ, float angle);
```

but it rotates around 0,0 coordinate, and I want rotating shape around its center.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html) for ShapeRenderer the second example shows you how to set the center of the box at position {20, 12, 2} and rotate around the z-axis using translate.  You need to do the same thing e.g.

```
this.m_ShapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Rectangle);
this.m_ShapeRenderer.setColor(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
this.m_ShapeRenderer.identity();
this.m_ShapeRenderer.translate(20.f, 10.f, 0.f);
this.m_ShapeRenderer.rotate(0.f, 0.f, 1.f, 45.f);
this.m_ShapeRenderer.rect(x, y, 40.f, 20.f);
this.m_ShapeRenderer.end();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not working for me. If I don't translate, my rectangle is displayed but is blinking rapidly. If I translate it, the rectangle is no longer visible? Do you know a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Use this method ([official docs](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html#rect-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-)):

```
public void rect(float x, float y,
                 float originX, float originY,
                 float width, float height,
                 float scaleX, float scaleY,
                 float degrees)
```

*Draws a rectangle in the x/y plane using ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line or ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled. The x and y specify the lower left corner. The originX and originY specify the point about which to rotate the rectangle.*

Use it like this:
(x and y is the point in the center of the rectangle)

```
renderer.rect(x-width/2, y-height/2, 
              width/2, height/2, 
              width, height, 
              1.0f, 1.0f, 
              myRotation);
```

Comment: This works great.  Just make sure originX and originY are relative to the bottom left of the rectangle, and not the world space...as I finally figured out...